# My application Suddenly force closing when clicking the button for sweet dialog

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

I created a fragment with a button on it and the application Suddenly force closing when clicking the button for sweet dialog, This is my code

```
Button btnricemeal1;


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab_fragment_1, container, false);

    btnricemeal1 = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.btnricemeal1);

    btnricemeal1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            SweetAlertDialog sd = new SweetAlertDialog(getActivity(),SweetAlertDialog.PROGRESS_TYPE);
            sd.setTitleText("Here's a message!");
            sd.show();
        }
    });
    return v;
}
```

logcat

```
 E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.raynard.kopiaveandroidapplication, PID: 32710
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unknown animation name: cn.pedant.SweetAlert.Rotate3dAnimation error:null
        at cn.pedant.SweetAlert.OptAnimationLoader.createAnimationFromXml(OptAnimationLoader.java:77)
        at cn.pedant.SweetAlert.OptAnimationLoader.createAnimationFromXml(OptAnimationLoader.java:64)
        at cn.pedant.SweetAlert.OptAnimationLoader.createAnimationFromXml(OptAnimationLoader.java:41)
        at cn.pedant.SweetAlert.OptAnimationLoader.loadAnimation(OptAnimationLoader.java:22)
        at cn.pedant.SweetAlert.SweetAlertDialog.<init>(SweetAlertDialog.java:80)
        at com.example.raynard.kopiaveandroidapplication.TabFragment1$1.onClick(TabFragment1.java:37)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4780)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19866)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
```

Comment: can u show logcat?

Comment: post the error log please.

Comment: note: the SweetAlertDialog library is 4 years old

Comment: @aminography why u remove logcat ? when he put in this page ? dont edit please xD

Comment: @Alireza: I do not remove logs, it's because of simultaneous edits man :)

Comment: Looks like an error in Sweet dialog thingy

Comment: so how am i going to fix it :(

Comment: Do you want something like loading progress dialog?

Comment: i'm just trying to make it appear, then i am going to create a dialog that can choose from the items inside the dialog

Comment: What is the classpath version you are using in Project Gradle (the first gradle)

Comment: com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.4